# How to remove spacing between lines in sharepoint?

Tags: css, image, sharepoint, spacing

In order to get some preferred formatting I split 1 image into 10x10 smaller images and I am inputting them onto a page in sharepoint to recreate the image, then will assign links to some of the images to match the overall shape. (Trying to make buttons in the shape of hexagons, trapezoids).

Anyways, problem is ocurring when I go from one line down to the next, I have a small white gap in between that breaks up the larger image. I have removed the horizontal and vertical spacing in the image editing ribbon, tried shift + enter, running the line onto the next with no enter. I also have added padding: 0px and border: 0px to the source code for each image. Both times it actually makes the problem worse, by adding horizontal spacing and including the vertical spacing?

I just need my images to directly stack on top of each other with no spacing.

```
<p dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
   <img alt="13.png" src="..." style="margin: 0px; width: 80px; height: 71px;"/>
   <img alt="23.png" src="..." style="margin: 0px; width: 80px; height: 71px;"/>
   <br/>
   <img alt="14.png" src="..." style="margin: 0px; width: 80px; height: 71px;"/>
   <img alt="24.png" src="..." style="margin: 0px; width: 80px; height: 71px;"/>
   <br/> 
   <br/> &#160;</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, this is your result now: [image: now]

And you want to achieve this:[image: expected]

If that's the case, all you need to do is add `display: flex;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the div parent of your images, like this:

```
<style>
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container img {
  width: 10%;
}
</style>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
    .
    .
    .
    <img src="..." />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That almost worked... once I added it all my images were on one line, trying to shift+ enter to break it up into multiple lines all the sudden I had gaps everywhere and weird spacing. TOtally messed with it. I probably added it incorrectly, including the source code in my main post. Where should I be adding the display and flex-wrap functions?

Comment: Change your code with the following code:

`<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; width: 800px;">
    <img alt="13.png" src="..." style="width: 80px; height: 71px;" />
    <img alt="23.png" src="..." style="width: 80px; height: 71px;" />
</div>`
Also, you don't need to add `<br/>` anymore

Comment: Awesome! it was presetting the width so it overflows that was tripping me up! Thank you!